# How to check if document exist with particular field in mongodb

Tags: javascript, python, mongodb

I have an array of users and I have one collection named users. Now I want to find the documents which has user_id equals to users from Array. And if that user id doesn't exist then no action taken. I'll loop through array to get one user id at a time. Now my concern is how to find the document with that particular user_id in MongoDB

Output I want:

```
Array a= [1,2,3,4,5]
document with user_id=1
document with user_id=2
document with user_id=3 like that
```

Thanks for help!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use $in operator. For more information https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

For example

```
db.collection.find({user_id:{$in:[1,2,3,4,5]}})
```